# Is there a way to ease the pain of setting Windows 11 file associations?

Tags: script, windows-11, automation, file-association

I just used Windows 11 for the first time and the file association business there is really awful, I have to set every single extension one by one to my preferred application. Whereas on Windows 10, I can just set what I want to be the photo viewer, the browser, the video player, the music player, etc.

Is there some kind of way to make this process easier on Windows 11? Maybe somebody has made an automation tool or something?

When I looked around, this seems to have been a problem for a long while now so I thought maybe somebody has already come up with a solution for it.

Comment: You could in theory set the assosication on Windows 10 and just export the keys and import them on Windows 11

Comment: @Ramhound how do you mean?

Comment: The UI to set the default application for a file extension changed, between Windows 10 and Windows 11, regardless of the version you are using the key that handles that file association is the same.  All this means is you can set it on a Windows 10 install, export the registry keys for those file extensions, and import them on your Windows 11 installation.